# TPL generic list usage

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I create parallel tasks and these tasks uses same static lists, I know that while coding multithread application lock is enough to make list threadsafe, but is it work with TPL too ?

```
 public static TSource FirstOrDefaultThreadSafe<TSource>(this List<TSource> source, Func<TSource, bool> predicate) where TSource : new()
    {
        var result=new TSource();
        try
        {               
                lock (source)
                {
                    result = source.FirstOrDefault(predicate);                                   
            }                
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {                
            throw ex;
        }


 Task.Factory.StartNew(() => FirstOrDefaultThreadSafe(List,predicate), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning);
```

or if two parallel task can reach to same list?

Comment: It's hard to say without actually seeing more of your code: e.g. how does the other thread access the `List`?

Answer (score 1):

If you're just reading from the list and the list is not being changed in the meanwhile then there is even no need to use that lock block.

You should be worried about thread-safety if you're changing it somewhere.